# I would like to ask in IBM Datastage about how to count number of rows for particular column

Tags: datastage

I have a question to ask about IBM Datastage. I want to do for a particular few columns, if the whole column is blank, then I want it to grab data from previous month and add it into the column. But if that column has just one value then I don't want it to grab data.

To make it clear, for example, Customer ID column, it has 500 rows and if the whole column is blank, I want it to grab data from previous month. But if the Customer ID column has 1 value out of 500, even 499 rows are blank, I still don't want it to grab data.

Is it possible to do it? Thank you in advance if anyone can help in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine multiple solutions:

1. Three jobs - one to determine the existence of a value for the months, the second to select the regular (current month) data and a third one to sleect the previous month data. Put all of them in a sequence and have a condition after the first job to go either in the one or other direction
2. Three parts of a single SQL statement again to check the extistence select either way. Select an artificial column (i.e. source) and set it to 1,2 or 3 in these statements to differeniate the source.Have transformer with a filter condition to filter depending on the result of the first statement.

Other solutions are possible but the "best" really depends on additional needs and requirements you have